# Command for Exiting Package Manager Console

Tags: nuget

Just curious, but is there in fact no exit command one might issue at the PM>  prompt in the NuGet Package Manager Console in Visual Studio?  ctrl+tab doesn't seem to work for me. So the only way is to close the Package Manager Console window? Fine with me, as long as this never causes a problem. It does seem a bit inelegant, but I suppose that's of little import.
. . .
Thanks for your attention,
Tallisfan

Answer (score 1):

Position your cursor onto the Nugget Manager Console thereafter just type <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>, you're done!

It is an old Geburtsfehler (bug by birth) persistent even in the last Visual Studio 2019. No more 100% sure old  you could type exit by the prompt (PM>)

Answer (score 0):

Click the clear tab at the top right side of the package manager console window

[image]